# Wine Crossover .... Application tried to create a window

Tags: upgrade, wine

On running any win32 app via crossover / wine butchery ...

Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded. Unknown error (127).

... and ...

err:module:load_builtin_dll failed to load .so lib for builtin L"winex11.drv": /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: undefined symbol: xcb_poll_for_reply64

It's a bit like this ... https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?p=29584

and this... https://www.codeweavers.com/support/forums/general/?t=26;mhl=190133;msg=190133

Ideas welcome!

OS: 32 bit Debian Wheezy / Puppy / Hybrid monster (... it's ... aliveeee!!! )

Intel Graphics Card

root@dog:~# /opt/cxoffice/bin/wine --version Product Name: CrossOver Linux Public Version: 13.2.0 Product Version: 13.2.0.27771 Build Tag: cxoffice-13.2.0rc1 Build Timestamp: 20140708T163719Z root@dog:~#

root@dog:~# glxinfo name of display: :0.0 display: :0 screen: 0 direct rendering: Yes server glx vendor string: SGI server glx version string: 1.4 server glx extensions: GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_libglvnd, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_INTEL_swap_event client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI client glx version string: 1.4 client glx extensions: GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_EXT_buffer_age GLX version: 1.4 GLX extensions: GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_INTEL_swap_event OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel�� GM45 Express Chipset x86/MMX/SSE2 OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 13.0.6 OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20 OpenGL extensions: GL_ARB_multisample, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture_object, etc etc ...

root@dog:~# /cry ... /drink ... /sleep ...

Comment: replaced libX11.so.6 with an earlier version from backup. 2D apps now launch eg.  wine notepad <<< that works. Games and 3d packages still fail broken elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same issue just now.

`err:module:load_builtin_dll failed to load .so lib for builtin L"winex11.drv": /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: undefined symbol: xcb_poll_for_reply64
Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Unknown error (127).`

I believe it is a wine version specific issue, because I solved it upgrading wine from 1.7.4 to 3.20 (been a while).
I describe my setup:

- PlayOnLinux 4.3.4 (4.2.12 also works) from [Downloads](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html)
- Install your target app to a [New Virtual Drive](http://wiki.playonlinux.com/index.php/The_Configuration_Window#.2810.29_-_New_Virtual_Drive_button)
- [Manage Wine Versions](http://wiki.playonlinux.com/index.php/The_Configuration_Window#.2813.29_-_Wine_Version_selection)